# I am getting this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL 'undefined' is invalid."

Tags: javascript, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

```
this.webSocket = new WebSocket(this.consumer.url);
```

when i ran my project i received this error on this line in file action_cable.self
please ask for any further code if needed.

Comment: `this.consumer.url` is `undefined`

Comment: i am following this [link](https://medium.com/@dhh/rails-5-action-cable-demo-8bba4ccfc55e#.jqcehn3ac) tutorial. u can see he also didn't define it